# jQuery call inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am calling function country change than it displaying error Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined How can I resolve this please help me. and thanks for last answer and editing. and sorry for my weak English.

```js
$(function(){
        var autocomplete;
        var geocoder;
        var input = document.getElementById('cityzip');

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    function search(){
        var location = autocomplete.getPlace();
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var lat = location['geometry']['location'].lat();
        var lng = location['geometry']['location'].lng();
        /*var data = {
            lng: lng,
            lat: lat
        }*/
        alert("search clicked");
        var pettype = [];
        var dogbreed = [];
        var catbreed = [];
        var color = [];
        var sex = [];
        $(".pettype:checked").each(function(){
            pettype.push($(this).val());
        })
        $(".dogbreed:checked").each(function(){
            dogbreed.push($(this).val());
        })
        $(".catbreed:checked").each(function(){
            catbreed.push($(this).val());
        })
        $(".color:checked").each(function(){
            color.push($(this).val());
        })
        $(".sex:checked").each(function(){
            sex.push($(this).val());
        })
            var data = {
                lng: lng,
                lat: lat,
                kmrange: $("#kmrange").val(),
                country: $("#country").val(),
                pettype: pettype,
                dogbreed: dogbreed,
                catbreed: catbreed,
                color: color,
                sex: sex,
            }
            console.log(data);
        }
        $("#location").click(function(){
            search();
        })
        $('#country').on('change', function() {
          search();
        })
```

Comment: When do you want to call `search()`. Be more specific.

Comment: Just FYI you can shorten the code by using `map()` instead of manually building an array with `each()`

Comment: Do you want to call `search()` function from external code?

Comment: You define search function. Now you can call it `search()` . What exactly you problem?

Comment: please check my edited question

Answer (score 3):

You can't call the search method from outside of the $(function() {}) block because of how scope works in javascript. However, you could do something like this:

```
var myNamespace = {};
$(function() {
    myNamespace.search = function() {};
});
```

then you could call myNamespace.search() from anywhere as long as the $(function() {}) has been executed already.